# Is there any way for my attached file to be above the signature?

Tags: gmail, attachment, email-signature

Like the title. I just wanted to ask how to get the attachment above the signature. I couldn't find any thing about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No there isn't.**

Still, you have **workaround options**:

1. If the file is an image, instead of attaching the file you can choose **Insert an image**.
2. If anything else (than an image), uploaded it somewhere and create a link to it so one can download it.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept.